# JSF snippet to center an image in a data table Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How can I align a graphicImage which will come as an element as a column in the middle .Now It is left aligned. I tried a lot but it will not work.

```
<p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Status" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:graphicImage value="../resources/images/Yellow_button.png"
    style="float:center;height: 18px; width: 20px"
        rendered="#{categorey.status == 1}" title="READY TO ZIP"/>
<p:column>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can align the table cell content for the whole column:

```
<p:column style="text-align: center">
   <f:facet name="header">
     <h:outputText value="Status" />
   </f:facet>
   <h:graphicImage value="../resources/images/Yellow_button.png" />
</p:column>
```

In order to separate the layout you can use the `styleClass` attribute referencing a class from a css resource as well.